# Detecting an unassigned register in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm just starting to learn verilog, and I've come across a situation where I'm trying to detect if a register has not yet been assigned a value. For instance, given the following code:

```
reg [3:0] r;
initial
    begin
        $display("r = %b", r);
        if (r == 4'bxxxx) $display("success");
        else $display("failure");
    end
```

When I run this code, I get this output:

```
r = xxxx
failure
```

I understand that I cannot compare r with 4'bxxxx, and I understand why I can't do this. But is there any other way to detect an unassigned register?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need the triple equal `===` operator for this. The result of `1'bx == 1'bx` is `x`, the result of `1'bx === 1'bx` is `true`.

http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/operators1.html